# How to update TableView Row using javaFx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to make some downloads and show the progress inside my table:

[image]

to do that I'm using the following classes:

```
public class DownloadDataTable {


    private SimpleDoubleProperty progress;
    private SimpleStringProperty type;
    private SimpleStringProperty status;

    public DownloadDataTable(double progress, String type, String status) {
        this.progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty(progress);
        this.type = new SimpleStringProperty(type);
        this.status = new SimpleStringProperty(status);
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return progress.get();
    }

    public void setProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress.set(progress);
    }

    public String getType() {
        String retorno;
        if (type==null){
            retorno="";
        }else{
            retorno=type.get();
        }
        return retorno;

    }

    public void setType (String type) {
        this.type.set(type);
    }

    public String getStatus(){
        String retorno;
        if (status==null){
            retorno="";
        } else{
            retorno=status.get();
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status){
        this.status.set(status);
    }
}
```

and to create the TitledPane, tableview and column tables I'm doing this:

```
public void addDownloadToTitledPane(DownloadContent downloadContent) {

        MetaDados metaDado = downloadContent.getMetaDado();

        String title = metaDado.getName();

        if (title.length() > 60) {

            title = title.substring(0, 57) + "...";
        }
        TableView downloadTable = new TableView();

        TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, Double> progress = new TableColumn<>("progress");
        progress.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, Double>, TableCell<DownloadDataTable, Double>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<DownloadDataTable, Double> call(TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, Double> p) {

                final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(-1);

                final TableCell cell = new TableCell<DownloadDataTable, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Double t, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(t, bln);
                        if (bln) {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            progressBar.setProgress(t);
                            progressBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
                            setGraphic(progressBar);
                            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                        }
                    }
                };


                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });
        progress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DownloadDataTable, Double>("progress"));
        progress.setText("Progresso");

        TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String> type = new TableColumn<>("type");
        type.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String>, TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String> call(TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String> p) {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(empty ? null : getString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }

                    private String getString() {
                        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                    }
                };

                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });
        type.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DownloadDataTable, String>("type"));
        type.setText("Tipo");

        TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String> status = new TableColumn<>("status");
        status.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String>, TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String> call(TableColumn<DownloadDataTable, String> p) {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell<DownloadDataTable, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText(empty ? null : getString());
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }

                    private String getString() {
                        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
                    }
                };

                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                return cell;
            }
        });

        status.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DownloadDataTable, String>("status"));
        status.setText("Status");

        downloadTable.getColumns().addAll(progress, type, status);

        List<PendingComponents> pendingComponents = downloadContent.getPendingComponents();

        ObservableList<DownloadDataTable> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (PendingComponents pendingComponent : pendingComponents) {

            String typeComponent;

            if (pendingComponent.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.HTML)) {
                typeComponent = "Conteúdo Principal";
            } else {
                typeComponent = "Pacote de Imagens";
            }
            data.add(new DownloadDataTable(-1, typeComponent, "Preparando download"));
        }

        downloadTable.setItems(data);
        downloadTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        TitledPane downloadPane = new TitledPane(title, downloadTable);

        downloadPane.setId(metaDado.getOfflineUuid());
        vBoxDownload.getChildren().add(downloadPane);
    }
```

Until here everything seems to works fine, but when I try to recover my table and update the data, my table is not updated. I've debbuged and everything seems to work, even the data value is changed, but my table still without update. See my code:

```
private void publishProgress(final String msg) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TitledPane titledPane = (TitledPane) controller.vBoxDownload.lookup("#"+metaDado.getOfflineUuid());
            TableView table = (TableView) titledPane.getContent();

            DownloadDataTable data = (DownloadDataTable) table.getItems().get(0);
            data.setProgress(100);
            data.setStatus(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

If I try to remove and add my row it doesn't work, but if I just add another row with the new values, I got a old row with the same value and a new row with new values. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong, someone can help me??

Comment: Please examine the entries of [this search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx-2%5D+or+%5Bjavafx%5D+tableview+refresh+row+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) and if the problem persists update your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add/remove the row to get the table to update when the progress value changes.

The problem is that you're not making the progress property accessible to the TableView.  This causes the **progress.setCellValueFactory(...)** call to wrap your getProgress() value in a new ObservableObjectWrapper.  This allows the value to display in the TableView, but it won't notify the table when the value is changed.

Add the following to your DownloadDataTable class, and your table will update when the value changes:

```
public SimpleDoubleProperty progressProperty() {
    return this.progress;
}

public SimpleStringProperty typeProperty() {
    return this.type;
}

public SimpleStringProperty statusProperty() {
    return this.status;
}
```

Comment: is this somewhere in the documentation?  Thank you @jhsheets

Comment: It's in the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html