# JavaFx ProgressBar Bind SimpleDoubleProperty

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I am using a progressbar in a tableview, where I'm using bind on his property so that when the value is changed, progressbar is started:

```
private SimpleDoubleProperty progressBar;

    public Tabela(Double progressBar) {
    this.progressBar = new SimpleDoubleProperty(progressBar);
    }

        public Double getProgressBar() {
    return progressBar.get();
}

public DoubleProperty getProgressBarProperty() {
    return progressBar;
}

public void setProgressBar(Double progressBar) {
    this.progressBar.set(progressBar);
}

public void setProgressBar(SimpleDoubleProperty progressBar) {
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}
```

And in my Hbox am using progressbar as follows:

```
  final ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();
  progress.setMinWidth(324.0);
  progress.progressProperty().bind(tabela.getProgressBarProperty());
```

So I'm using a  so that after a certain time the value is changed, ie I will control the progressbar. The value is changed, but in my tableview nothing happens, but when I change the column position to another, the progressbar is running.

The same happens with "label", i changed for "text" and it work, but if the progressbar I have to use.

have a way to force the 'tableview' refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the JavaFX naming standard to get TableViews and other widgets to properly refresh when an observable object changes.  For instance, you should rename getProgressBarProperty() to progressBarProperty().

See: [How to update TableView Row using javaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948416/how-to-update-tableview-row-using-javafx/17960766#17960766)

Comment: You really should review the link I posted, as the person was doing the same thing as you.  Use setCellFactory to display the actual ProgressBar widget in the table cell, and setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela,Double>("progressBar")), which will use reflection to automatically to bind to progressBarProperty() so the table gets notified that it needs to redraw when the value change.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. But now I need to put a "Text" next to the progressbar, would make a "bind" with the property of my other "class", but  not working. I posted the code so you can see better

Comment: Saying it's not working doesn't tell me what your problem is.  If your Tabela class has method progressBarProperty(), then your cell value factory needs to set columSituacao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, Double>("progressBar")).  If you renamed the method to progressProperty() then you could use columSituacao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, Double>("progress")).  You must spell the name of the property to bind to appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There would be something wrong in this source?

class table

```
 ...

 public Tabela(String nome, Double progressBar, String etapa) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.progressBar = new SimpleDoubleProperty(progressBar);
    this.etapa = new SimpleStringProperty(etapa);
}

....
```

Add new line.

```
      private void preencheListaNomeTabelas() {
      getLista().add(new Tabela("Test", 0.0, "Test Text"));
```

Add hbox in table.

```
columTabela.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, String>("nome"));
    columSituacao.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Tabela, Double>, TableCell<Tabela, Double>>() {
        public TableCell<Tabela, Double> call(TableColumn<Tabela, Double> p) {

            final HBox box = new HBox();
            box.setPrefHeight(25.0);

            final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(-1);

            final Text text = new Text();
            **text.textProperty().bind(..); //I would use here the**

            BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
            border.setTop(text);
            border.setBottom(progressBar);
            BorderPane.setAlignment(text, Pos.CENTER);

            box.getChildren().add(border);

            final TableCell cell = new TableCell<Tabela, Double>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Double t, boolean bln) {
                    super.updateItem(t, bln);
                    if (bln) {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        progressBar.setProgress(t);
                        progressBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
                        setGraphic(box);
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                    }
                }
            };

            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        }
    });
    columSituacao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tabela, Double>("progress"));
    columSituacao.setText("Progresso");

    tableView.getItems().addAll(lista);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

task

```
    Task t = new Task() {

        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            getLista().get(0).setEtapa("Lendo PostgreSQL");
            getLista().get(0).setProgressBar(-1.0);
            return null;
        }

    };
    new Thread(t).start();
```