# Why do I have to copy the list of selected items from a JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a TableView backed by an ObservableList:

```
private ObservableList<Renderer> renderers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private TableView<Renderer> renderersTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Renderer, String> nameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Renderer, Boolean> approvedColumn;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    approvedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("approved"));
    renderersTable.setItems(this.renderers);
}
```

The Renderer objects are very simple and look like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Renderer extends Model {
    private String name;
    private boolean approved;
    // ...
}
```

In this piece of code I get all the selected items from the TableView and process them:

```
private void approveSelectedRenderers() {
    ObservableList<Renderer> selectedRenderers = renderersTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    for (Renderer renderer : selectedRenderers) {
        renderer.setApproved(true);
        renderers.set(renderers.indexOf(renderer), renderer);
    }
}
```

I have enabled multiple select and indeed selectedRenderers shows the appropriate count, but the loop is only executed once.

If instead I make a copy, like this:

```
private void approveSelectedRenderers() {        
    // Get all the selected renderers but copy them.
    List<Renderer> selectedRenderers = new ArrayList<>();          
    selectedRenderers.addAll(renderersTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

    for (Renderer renderer : selectedRenderers) {
        renderer.setApproved(true);
        renderers.set(renderers.indexOf(renderer), renderer);
    }
}
```

it works correct and all items are processed. What's going on? What's the appropriate way of dealing with this?

Comment: What is the `allRenderes` for datastructure? Is it a separate datastructure, or the (observable) backing datastructure of tbe `TableView`?

Comment: As in your other question, you don't have to do anything of the sort. You have errors elsewhere in code you didn't post that is causing you to believe you have to jump through these unnecessary hoops.

Comment: @n247s: it is the observable backing the TableView.

Comment: Really? downvotes and close because this is not a programming question?

Comment: no - because you do nothing to make this question answerable ;) You are doing something wrong somewhere ... we can't know what that might be without a SSCCE (or in newer terms http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) - with your rep you should know the procedure ;)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your other question you are actually modifying the backing (observable) datastructure of the TableView. This means you are resetting the complete selected (observable) List be resetting the Renderer in the backing datastructure. Im kinda suprised it doesnt throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Solution: Simply dont modify the backing datastructure when looping over the selected List. It is also not nessecary to reset them after updating. If you change the value type (boolean) to `SimpleBooleanProperty`, you can pass it directly to the TableView (using the CellFactory). Changing the value of the `SimpleBooleanProperty` will automatically update the table for you.

When using a `SimpleBooleanProperty` is not possible, you could also use the `TableView#refresh()` method. Be aware though that it will repopulate the entire TableView instead of just the modified elements.

Further reading: [Simular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948416/how-to-update-tableview-row-using-javafx)

Comment: "Be aware though that it will repopulate the entire TableView instead of just the modified elements." AFAIK all it will do is re-render the visible cells. You are pretty unlikely to have more than 20 or so rows visible, unless your user has an enormous screen.

Comment: But I do need to loop over the selected rows and modifying them. Not doing that is either not doing anything, or doing what I'm already doing which is making a copy.

Comment: @Pablo You don't need to copy the list to iterate over it and modify its contents. The only reason your code doesn't work when you try it without copying the list (as explained in this answer) is that you call `renderers.set(...)` during the iteration, which changes the list over which you are iterating. If you remove this call, the loop will execute as expected. If you implement your model as suggested in the Javadocs for `TableColumn` and `PropertyValueFactory`, you don't need the `renderers.set(...)` call anyway.